# IdentityServer3 Issue partial login cookie

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I currently have a sign up link on my Idsrv login page that redirects to MVC signup pages hosted on same pipeline as Idsrv. The sign-up flow is as follows:

1. Create acccount (email & password) and save to DB.
2. Select subscription and purchase it (storing purchase info in DB with userId).
3. Redirect back to client app

In the past the sign up link on the login page would bring the user to the account creation page and after they entered in email & password I would issue an Idsrv login cookie using this code:

```
var login = new AuthenticatedLogin
                {
                    IdentityProvider = IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.BuiltInIdentityProvider,
                    Subject = user.Id,
                    Name = user.UserName
                };

   this.Request.GetOwinContext().Environment.IssueLoginCookie(login);
```

The subscription & purchase pages were decorated with [IdentityServerFullLogin] attributes to ensure only authorized users accessed them.

I have since added external login support and am using Partial Login to redirect a new external user to this signup sequence before completing their local account setup. The problem I'm running into is now I have [IdentityServerPartialLogin] and [IdentityServerFullLogin] attributes that need to be on the same controller methods which obviously doesn't work. I'm wondering how to modify my original sign up sequence (using sign up link) to use partial login instead of full login and issuing a full-login cookie. It seems like there needs to be an Environment.IssuePartialLoginCookie() method to accomplish what I need to do but am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to change how you perform your authorization. Instead of using those attributes, you would do it explicitly/manually in the action methods themselves. There are easy OWIN extension methods to learn if the user has either of those two login types: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/owin.html

Comment: Got it, ended up creating a custom IAuthenticationFilter that uses GetIdentityServerPartialLoginAsync & GetIdentityServerFullLoginAsync to ensure the user is either partially or fully logged in. Thanks!